# Strange behaviour of WebActivities under Firefox OS 1.2

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I am writting a firefox os [application](https://github.com/bakaibalazs/sonar-firefoxos-application) and I found a strange problem. I have two web activities (open a link on a projects tab and sending an e-mail on the users tab ) what are work correctly under the Firefox OS 1.1 simulator but not work under the appmanager+firefox OS 1.2 simulator. In additional it did not work under my Keon phone with FFOS 1.2 prerelease.

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might not be the most optimal way but try something like:

```
function sendEmail(toEmail, subject, body) {
  var createEmail = new MozActivity({
    name : "new",
    data : {
      type : "mail",
      url : "mailto:" + toEmail + "?&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body + "",
    }
  });
}
function processUsers() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
      for (var i = 0; i < obj['users'].length; i++) {
        if (obj['users'][i].email != null) {
            var myLi = document.createElement('li');
            myLi.innerHTML = "<p>" + obj['users'][i].name+ "</p>" + "<p class='sendEmail'>" + obj['users'][i].email; "</p>";
            var em =obj['users'][i].email;
            var sb = '';
            var bd = '';
            myLi.onclick = (function(em, sb, bd) {
                return function(){ sendEmail(em, sb, bd) }
            })(em, sb, bd);
          $('#resultsUsers').append(myLi);
        } else {
          $('#resultsUsers').append("<li><p>" + obj['users'][i].name + "</p></li>");
        }
      }
      usersAreLoaded = true;
    } else {
      console.log("did not get data " + xhr.status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline JavaScript code inside onclick etc will not run in privileged apps, see the docs about [app CSP (content security policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/CSP):

> Inline scripts are banned. You may not use script attributes like
>   onclick="" or onload="".

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!